# How to write_message to a websocket while firestore on_snapshot is not awaitable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, tornado

I have to subscribe real-time update from Firestore then send them over websocket in Tornado

I tried to use IOLoop.run_in_executor, IOLoop.run_on_executor, @gen.coroutine, 
async await, non of them working.
The only success way is assign change to some variable then use PeriodicCallback to send them through websocket, but this is not a real-time way.

```py
class SocketHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self, sport, event):
        f = firestore.Client()
        query_ref = f.collection('some_col').document('some_doc')
        # Can not await here
        query_watch = query_ref.on_snapshot(self.callback)

    def callback(self, doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
        for change in changes:
            if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
                # Not possible to write_message because the event loop is done
                self.write_message('ADDED')
```

I have to push the change as soon as I receive an update from Firestore to a websocket.

**Edit**

on_snapshot is open thread by itself, but the event loop continue.

after change coming from Firestore, it is to late, the event loop is done.

How can I write_message while no event loop is running?

Comment: `on_snapshot` creates a new thread in the background to listen for new updates. Probably that's the reason it's not working with Tornado properly.

Comment: add_callback do work for me but I can not terminate the background process